# How to format a float, up to "n" decimal places without trailing zeros

Tags: javascript

How to format number in JavaScript like c# as 0.#### ?

I use function `.toFixed(4)` but It's format `0.0000`

```js
var x = a / b;
console.log(x.toFixed(4));
```

I want to format like this...

```
1.0000 -> 1

1.2000 -> 1.2

1.2300 -> 1.23

1.2340 -> 1.234

1.2345 -> 1.2345

1.23456... -> 1.2346
```

Comment: why not? I already search but not found.

Comment: @Sophairk show an example that is not working, with values please

Comment: please see example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine `Number.prototype.toFixed()` with a small `RegExp` replacement

```js
console.log(x.toFixed(4).replace(/\.?0+$/, ''))
```

```js
const nums = ['1.0000', '1.2000', '1.2300', '1.2340', '1.2345', '1.23456']

const rx = /\.?0+$/
nums.forEach(num => {
  console.info(num, ' -> ', parseFloat(num).toFixed(4).replace(rx, ''))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> The toFixed() method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

toFixed won't give you result in such format, you can change the values after decimal using regex

```js
let a = 4
let b = 3
let x = ( a / b ).toFixed(4)

console.log(x.replace(/\.(.*)$/g,(match,g1)=>{
  return `.${g1 ? '#'.repeat(g1.length) : ''}` 
}));
```

> Update

```js
let a = 4
let b = 3

let changedFormat = (a,b) => {
 return ( a / b ).toFixed(4).replace(/\.?0+$/g, '')    
}

console.log(changedFormat(a,b))
console.log(changedFormat(1,1))
console.log(changedFormat(6,4))
```

Comment: Why bother with all the string replacement ~ `\`${Math.floor(a/b)}.####\``

Comment: 4 / 3 = 1.3333... result should 1.3333 is not 1.####

Comment: @Phil to keep it generic, so that it will work even if the value passed to `toFixed` is dynamic

Comment: @Sophairk this answer was based on your original question which really didn't make any sense in a JavaScript context

Comment: you don't understand what I want. please see example

Comment: @Sophairk i have updated answer as per update of question